# Есть ли команда для отложенного удаления директории в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Как удалить директорию со всеми вложениями в Ubuntu, знаю:

```
rm -rf dir_name
```

А можно ли сказать **Ubuntu**, чтобы она удалила файл через 1 минуту, например?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так

```
$ echo "rm -rf dir_name" | at "now + 1 min"
```

Comment: Что-то здесь не так, какой-нибудь `echo` не забыли случайно?

Comment: Удалился сразу - не ожидая 1 минуты (((

Comment: @andreymal, да с **echo** по таймеру удаляет. Спасибо!

Comment: @andreymal неправильно копипасту поправил :) А в at разве тоже кавычки нужны?

Comment: странно, но данная команда не удаляет ровно через минуту, если например запустить эту команду по системному времени в 15:19:45 то удалится в 15:20:00 то есть через  15 секунд а не 60 как должно быть. Похоже она просто округляет до ближайшей минуты.

Answer (score 1):

```
{sleep 1m && rm -rf FILE} &!
```

> Использование: sleep ЧИСЛО[СУФФИКС]…
> или:    sleep ПАРАМЕТР Приостанавливает выполнение на заданное ЧИСЛО секунд. СУФФИКС может принимать значение «s», что означает
> секунды (применяется по умолчанию), «m» — минуты, «h» — часы и «d» —
> дни. ЧИСЛО может быть не целым. Если задано несколько аргументов,
> выполнение приостанавливается на период, равный сумме их значений.